# Prevent From submit even if error happens

Tags: html, forms

I prevent a form from being submitted in this way:

```
<form onsubmit="call_my_function(); return false;" >
```

The problem is that if any error happens in `call_my_function()` then form submits. Is there any better way of prevention?

Comment: why don't you put the function behind a (input) button instead of submitting the form with the submit button?

Comment: What are the nature of the errors? exceptions or validation errors? Lets see some code

Comment: @jonasvermeulen you are right

Comment: @skyfoot exception. but better to prevent all!

Comment: @user2604405 that is another problem(answer of that question is a part of sentence in my question)

Comment: @jonasvermeulen i did that and worked fine. thanks so much. you may leave as answer.

Comment: @werva, just added the answer :) glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the function behind a (input) button instead of submitting the form with the submit button

Comment: the most reliable way

Answer (score 0):

Use the return false statement inside the function call_my_function. Something lke this:

```
call_my_function(){
/*Your code*/
return false;
}
```

This will prevent it from submitting. If you are using jQuery, then `event.preventDefault()` is preferable option.

Comment: if error happens in `/*your code*/` then `return false` doesnt run.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.
Add a try catch in the function

**HTML Part**

**JavaScript Part**

```
call_my_function(){
    try
      {
      //Run some code here
    return false;
      }
    catch(err)
      {
     document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
      }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below similar questions:--

Hope you will get some idea:-

[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

[JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission)